# Ubuntu install with Dual boot Win7. Win 7 is not a boot option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu on Windows 7 system
After Ubuntu install, I no longer see Win7 as an option
Ubuntu is working fine.

I read on the forum to install boot-repair.
I run the recommended fix option. I do see Grub at the boot time. 
However I still do not see Windows 7 as a boot option.

Here is my weblink
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14502183/
(I am not a computer expert, so I dont know how to edit/make changes)

I also tried to recover via photorec. I think I can see the file.
Just dont know what to do.

> >
>   Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>   Disk /dev/sda - 320 GB / 298 GiB (RO) - WDC WD3200BEKT-60V5T1
>
> >

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Windows boot option because there's no Windows on the disk.
You have installed Ubuntu in legacy mode and it is the only system installed.
When you want to have the Windows system back, you have to reinstall it.

In this case it is recommended to first install Windows and then Ubuntu.
When you decide so, consider to install the 64 bit version of Ubuntu.
Sorry for being the harbinger of these news, but unfortunately ...

Note : You said ... "I installed Ubuntu on Windows 7 system ..." Did you use wubi ?
In case you did : Don't do it (again) - this is absolutely not the recommended way.
Create a DVD or USB Ubuntu installation media, boot from it and install Ubuntu !